# QuickBooks Desktop Web Connector Post Payroll PHP

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

Hi everyone. I have been looking high and low for a solution to my issue below.

I am trying to have a PHP application post information to Quick Books Desktop edition via the `webconnector`. I have found examples at various sources, however none I have found have a solution to post payroll information.

The solutions I see are:

- Mysql Mirror QB using consolibytes library (How do I get it to include payroll data?) Can you only post via this method instead of mirroring?
- Using the consolibytes library to somehow insert payroll data without mirror
- Using QBXML to post

Does anyone have any examples of any solutions, or know of any good online resources in which it is documented. Unfortunately Intuit seems to have updated their website over the last week or so and now all forum links are defunct.

Any help is much appreciated, I am stumped!

Comment: Depending on what payroll information you are trying to post, the SDK will probably not be able to do it. You might want to include what data you are trying to send across. Yes, the forums have been shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QuickBooks APIs (e.g. QuickBooks itself) do NOT support directly adding payroll information directly to QuickBooks. This is a limitation of QuickBooks itself.

Usually, the work-around/way to get this data is in via time sheets. You can add the time sheets to QuickBooks, and then use the payroll stuff in QuickBooks to do your payroll/cut checks from the time sheets.

If you're considering using the SQL mirror stuff, make sure you read this first:

- [QuickBooks PHP SQL Mirror - beta, be careful!](http://consolibyte.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=20)

The more appropriate way to do what you're asking is to use the Web Connector, and adapt the quick-start script to send `TimeTrackingAdd` requests to QuickBooks.

- [PHP + QuickBooks quick-start](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start)

Use the OSR to look up `TimeTrackingAdd` (use the Select Message drop-down box, and click the XMLOps tab):

- [QuickBooks OSR](https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html)

If/when you have QuickBooks, either ask on StackOverflow, or feel free to use our [QuickBooks PHP developer forums](http://consolibyte.com/forum/).